# How to restore OS X drive to factory defaults?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I turned off the Core Storage volume manager on my OS X partition (i.e. `diskutil cs revert`). Now my Recovery HD displays in Disk Utility and in Startup Manager.

I don't like this and would like to undo this change. For example, I can no longer boot from the recovery disk by holding Command+R at power on, instead it boots into Internet Recovery Mode.

I tried `diskutil cs convert` to change it back but I still see the Recovery HD everywhere.

Is there a way to completely restore the disk (and the partition CoreStorage settings, really the entire disk) to factory defaults?

Comment: If you have a 8 GB or larger flash drive and can still boot to OS X, you can download the OS X installer to a flash drive, boot from the flash drive, erase you internal drive and reinstall OS X.

Comment: DavidAnderson, Downloading the installer to the flash drive does not enable it to be booted from and a proper USB installer needs to be created from the installer that's downloaded to the internal hard drive in /Applications.

Comment: @user3439894: Assume you are referring to "[Create a bootable installer for OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)". I stand corrected. You must first download OS X from the App Store to your internal drive, then run a utility to transfer to a USB flash drive. But, if you really what factor defaults, then download OS X from Internet Recovery Mode.

Comment: Without specifying you Mac model and the system version there is nothing like a "factory default" **drive partition layout**. Depending on your model this may either be a default non-CoreStorage partition layout or two different CoreStorage layouts (SSD / Fusion Drive).

Answer (score 1):

I booted into Internet Recovery Mode, erased the entire hard drive, and re-installed Mac OS X. This will reinstall the OS that came with the computer, recreate EFI and Recovery Mode partitions, and set CoreStorage volumes as if everything is set from factory defaults.

After this Recovery Mode works as expected.